# jquery animate not working, div is not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a div appear and disappear gradually while moving at random, but it is not working, it is not moving, is fixed. Here's a sample of my problematic code. The div only disappears and appears. Help please.

CSS

```
div.a {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    position:fixed;    
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 var opacidad = [0.0, 1.0];
 var visibilidad = ['hidden', 'visible'];
 $(document).ready(function () {
     animateDiv();
 });
 function makeNewPosition() {
     var h = $(window).height() - 50;
     var w = $(window).width() - 50;
     var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
     var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
     return [nh, nw];
 }
 function animateDiv() {
     var newq = makeNewPosition();
     var oldq = $('.a').offset();
     var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
     movimiento(newq, speed);
 };
 function movimiento(newq, speed) {
     //alert(newq)
     var newq = Math.floor(parseFloat(newq) / 2);
     //alert(newq)
     $('.a').animate({
         top: newq[0],
         left: newq[1],
         opacity: opacidad[0]
     }, speed).css({
         visibility: visibilidad[0]
     })
     var newq = Math.floor(parseFloat(newq) * 2);
     //alert(newq)
     $('.a').animate({
         top: newq[0],
         left: newq[1],
         opacity: opacidad[1]
     }, speed)
         .css({
         visibility: visibilidad[1]
     }, function () {
         animateDiv()
     })
 }
 function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
     var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
     var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
     var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
     var speedModifier = 0.1;
     var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);
     return speed;
 }
```

Comment: First of all, I ser several problems in your movimiento function.  You have a parameter `newq` but then immediately define a local variable with the same name.  On top of that, you're treating it like a number, but the parameter is an array.  And then, you repeat a couple of lines.

Comment: Also, you added a .css() call right in the middle of your animate method call.  It should be at the end.  In fact, I don't even quite understand the point of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for, but here is a jsFiddle based on your code which randomly animates the position and opacity of the div.  I made corrections based on my comments above.

**UPDATE: I have updated the Fiddle according to your comment below.**

What I did:

1. In the movimiento function, we first must calculate the current position so that...
2. ...we can use it to calculate the halfway position to the new coordinates
3. Add an extra animation to the halfway point so that we can animate from opacity 0 to 1.
4. Set the easing to linear so both half animations are the same speed.  If you want to apply an easing value for the entire animation, it's much more complicated.

**UPDATE 2: Sorry, I made a mistake in calculating the halfway point.  Fixed.**

http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/Y69QK/6/

animateDiv();

```
function makeNewPosition() {
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];
}

function animateDiv() {
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.a').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
    movimiento(newq, speed);
};

function movimiento(newq, speed) {
    var currq = [
        $('.a').offset().top,
        $('.a').offset().left
    ],
    halfq  = [
        Math.floor(currq[0] + (newq[0]-currq[0])/2),
        Math.floor(currq[1] + (newq[1]-currq[1])/2)
    ];

    console.log("Animate from " +  + currq[0] + "," + currq[1] + " to: " + newq[0] + "," + newq[1] + " via: " + halfq[0] + "," + halfq[1] + " - speed: " + speed);    
    $('.a').animate({
        top: halfq[0],
        left: halfq[1],
        opacity: 1
    }, {
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: speed
    });

    $('.a').animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1],
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: speed,
        complete: animateDiv
    });
}

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]),
        y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]),
        greatest = x > y ? x : y,
        speedModifier = 0.1,
        speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I could not answer earlier. I need when div is starting, appears, and when div is stopping, disappears

Comment: DO you mean that you want it to fade in and out, so that it is 100% visible in the middle of its animation and 0% visible at the end?  Because logically, if it's a binary state where the div only disappears at the end, it will appear again immediately because the cycle will start over again.

Comment: yes, 0% visible at the end and at the begin. The 100% visible is only in the middle of the animation, as you said.